# Display GUI component In Ignition dynamically using Python/Jython Script

Tags: python, jython, scada, ignition, scada-ignition

Currently I am showing a number of user-defined GUI components (templates) (let's give it a name: *signal*) in some of my main windows. Those GUI components are spread around the windows and are quite a lot in number (>50 per window) and I have multiple of such windows.

[image]

I have created all those windows using Ignition GUI and so far they are done... but... Now, there is a requirement to make whatever signal is displayed in the GUI window to be shown in a list of GUI.

[image]

My questions are:

1. How to obtain list of GUI component (template) of the same type (signal) using `Ignition Python/Jython` Script?
2. How to get its custom properties (such as `customDisplayName`)
3. How to draw the GUI component (template) dynamically?

As of now, it is possible for me to drag and drop components (making exact copy of the displayed *signals*) in the container list I use to display the *signal* template. But since it is possible for new *signal* to be added in the GUI, I am looking for a more automated solution (if there is any).

Answer (score 3):

`Ignition` supports obtaining of the GUI components by `.components` from the container type component using `Jython` script.

So in the end, the implementation of my solution for this question was:

```
for comp in rootcontainer.components: #looping through every component in the root container
    if 'MySignal' in comp.name: #check the name of the component, see if it matches
        #do the logic here
```